# How to Convert secondary Node to primary if maximum of node down in a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb with replica set ,which have 3 nodes lets their ip's are 192.168.1.100 , 192.168.1.101,192.168.1.102 .

In MY current setup 192.168.1.100 is Primary and others are Secondary .I have set priority for 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101 is 1  and for 192.168.1.102 is 0 , now After some time my 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101 both node are down .

I want to force 192.168.1.102 to become primary so that My application will  live .
Is their is any way to  Forcefully convert 192.168.1.102 node to  become primary NODE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions to overcome from this situation is ,If there is only one node remains in replica set and that node is secondary(Having Priority 0) then first shutdown the node extract node from replica set (by comment repliSet line from mongod.conf or start mongo go to mongo command line use local modify records from system.replset and delete record) , then start node as a standalone mongodb :)

Answer (score 24):

You can achieve it without mongod service restart by below steps-

connect to active member suppose it is running on localhost on 27017 port:

```
mongo --port 27017
```

Get your member ids from here-

```
> use admin
> rs.status()
```

Suppose your active member id is 1. then reconfigure your replication as per below steps-

```
> cfg = rs.conf()
> cfg.members = [cfg.members[1]]
> rs.reconfig(cfg, {force : true})
```

It will make your remiaining active member to primary and available for application and writes.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this? If this happens at midnight someone needs to be available at midnight to run this command

Comment: for me cfg.members[1] didn't work, but cfg.members[0] worked.

Comment: First you need to get this id either 0, 1 or else by following command: rs.status(), as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm not confortable with this solution, because it just breaks the cluster configuration, and when the 2 missing nodes are up again, they do not reintegrate the cluster. Isn't it possible to just change the priority on the remaining member ?

Answer (score 7):

You can follow the steps [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/) to reconfigure replica set when a majority of members are not accessible.

As you have only one node left in the replica set, your data will not be replicated. You'd better add these two nodes back once they are alive.

Answer (score 7):

I sloved my issue by following as below:

Connect to a surviving member and save the current configuration. Consider the following example commands for saving the configuration:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
printjson(cfg)
```

On the same member, remove the down and unreachable members of the replica set from the members array by setting the array equal to the surviving members alone.

let's only the single member is remained

```
# Don't c/p if you have more than 1 node in your replica set
cfg.members = [cfg.members[0]]
```

member[0] is the one that is in frist in array what get in rs.conf()
reconfigure the set with the force option set to true:

```
rs.reconfig(cfg, {force : true})
```

Now you can see that surviving member is now PRIMARY.
Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/

Comment: Thanks, this worked like charm for me. I had 2 members left in the cluster and both were secondary. I was able to mark one primary following your instructions.

Comment: I get this `Reconfig did not succeed yet, starting new attempt...` over and over

Answer (score 1):

Not without manual intervention in this case. You will also suffer another problem. The majority of the set will be offline, this means that even without a priority of 0 your remaining replica member would not become primary.

Instead what you must do is either get the majority of the set back up or you must run a `rs.reconfig()` removing the two dead members of your set.

You cna find examples etc here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks For your Reply ,I did All steps mentioned in the given URL.Below is the error when i was running the query :
cfg.members=[cfg.member[0]]
Thu May  2 16:52:46.168 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined 

rs.reconfig(cfg,{force:true})
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: initiation and reconfiguration of a replica set must be sent to a node that can become primary",
        "code" : 13420,
        "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @user2334519 What ddi the configuration object look like when you sent it in? I think it might be `cfg.members=[cfg.member[0]]` should be `cfg.members=[cfg.members[0]]`

Comment: see the error below ,mongoreplset1:SECONDARY> cfg = rs.conf()
mongoreplset1:SECONDARY> printjson(cfg)
mongoreplset1:SECONDARY> cfg.members = [cfg.members[0]]
[ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "192.168.1.197:27017", "priority" : 0 } ]
mongoreplset1:SECONDARY> rs.reconfig(cfg, {force : true})
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: initiation and reconfiguration of a replica set must be sent to a node that can become primary",
        "code" : 13420,
        "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @user2334519 Yes, you also have to do another step, set its priority to 1

Comment: But How to set priority of secondary server when primary node is down ,below is error code For the Same:  mongoreplset1:SECONDARY> cfg.members[0].priority=1
1
mongoreplset1:SECONDARY> rs.reconfig(cfg)
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "replSetReconfig command must be sent to the current replica set primary."
}
mongoreplset1:SECONDARY>

Comment: @user2334519 Ah, yeah I see, I think you might have to restart the node as standalone, remove any configuration for replset it has on it and then restart it as a member `:/`

Comment: Hi Thanks For your Reply, Solutions  to overcome from this situation is ,If there is only one node remains in replica set and that node is secondary then first shutdown the node extract node from replica set (by comment repliSet line from mongod.conf or start mongo go to mongo command line use local modify records from system.replset and delete record)  , then start node as a standalone mongodb :)

Comment: @user2334519 np, sorry I couldn't give you a graceful non-destructive way of doing it :)

Comment: If only one remain node remain in ReplicaSet (i.e SECONDARY NODE having priority 0) and their is no fixed time For PRimary or other member  goes Live ,then there is Only one way follow  to live our Application/Site is Extract node from replicaSet and up it as standalone  server , THE Non-Destructive way :)   .

Comment: @user2334519 though do note that in standalone the member wont be able to rejoin a replica set without a restart (unless you init the replica set from the node), also you might have to restart your application with a new configuration if you run it in standalone mode, but indeed in terms of data loss it is non-destructive :) edit: actually even with init from that node it will require a restart :(